# Ngrok returns 405 error while tunneling my localhost

Tags: botframework, remote-access, http-status-code-405, ngrok, http-tunneling

I have a web app bot that I would like to remote it so a few people can test it. I am using Bot Framework Emulator to test it locally and it works wonders, but I'm thoroughly failing to make ngrok host it.

(I actually managed doing it using the ...azurewebsites.net/api/messages link my app has in Azure with another bot, but I couldn't with this one, so I'm trying with the link ngrok offers me - both bots, the one I managed and this one, are hosted in Azure, but I don't know how to make it available to remote access)

Steps I'm taking:

1. Deploy the app in Visual Studio so it runs on localhost:3979;
2. Open port externally in ngrok using `ngrok
   3979 http -host-header=rewrite localhost:3979`;
3. Get one of the forwarding URLs ngrok provides me, like
   `https://3d609207.ngrok.io`
4. Insert previous URL in Bot Framework Emulator;
5. Click Connect.

Both in ngrok and in Bot Framework Emulator returns me `405 Method Not Allowed`.

I tried accessing the link I inserted in Bot Framework Emulator and I normally have the page I would see while hosting my bot locally:

> Describe your bot here and your terms of use etc.
>
> Visit Bot Framework to register your bot. When you register it,
>   remember to set your bot's endpoint to
>
> https://your_bots_hostname/api/messages

But I can't send nor receive messages in Bot Framework Emulator.

Additionally, ngrok prints this under the HTTP request headline:

```
HTTP Requests
-------------

POST /                         405 Method Not Allowed
GET  /favicon.ico              200 OK
GET  /                         200 OK
```

My MSAppID and Password are configured properly in web.config, and compilation results in no error, so I doubt it's something on the code (unless there is some configuration in the code that prevents this bot being accessed remotely for a reason, but I have no idea).

I would very much appreciate any help on this issue. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Both in ngrok and in Bot Framework Emulator returns me 405 Method Not Allowed

I can reproduce the issue on my side if I just provide `https://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io` as message endpoint.

[image]

Please try to specify `https://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io/api/messages` as message endpoint, which works for me.

[image]

Comment: It worked!! Sorry for taking so long to reply, I had to focus on another project. For registration, I used `ngrok http [port] -host-header="localhost:[port]"` on ngrok and set the locale to the same port my Visual Studio was deploying. Thanks a lot.